# How to Implement this Haskell Function?

Tags: haskell

Unfortunately I am unable to implement this function I have tried a lot.

> f5 :: (Either a b -> c) -> (a -> c, b -> c)

I tried this

```
f5 k _ (Left x)     =  k x
f5 _ u (Right y)    =  u y
```

Thanks the help in advance .

Comment: Your function takes a single argument (a function `Either a b -> c`) and needs to return a pair of functions so it need to look like `f5 f = (\a -> ..., \b -> ...)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You implemented

```
f5 :: (a -> c) -> (b -> c) -> Either a b -> c
```

You need to do the opposite operation.

```
f5 :: (Either a b -> c) -> (a -> c, b -> c)
f5 f = (f . Left, f . Right)
```

Answer (score 3):

Let the types be your guide.

Your function should take one argument, a function of type `Either a b -> c`, and produce a pair of functions, `(a -> c, b -> c)`.

(The function you wrote takes three arguments and doesn't produce a pair.)

That is, you want

```
f5 f = (a_to_c, b_to_c)
```

where `f :: Either a b -> c`, `a_to_c :: a -> c` and `b_to_c :: b -> c`.

In order to create `a_to_c`, assume that you have an `a` and a function `Either a b -> c`.
Now, there's (only) one way you can make a function of type `a -> c` from those two things – create an `Either` from the `a` with `Left`, and then pass it to the "`Either` function".

Informally,

```
a_to_c x = f (Left x)
```

or

```
a_to_c = f . Left
```

The same reasoning for `b` leads to a similar situation with `b`.

```
b_to_c x = f (Right x)
```

or

```
b_to_c = f . Right
```

Putting them together

```
f5 f = (f . Left, f . Right)
```

or, more verbosely

```
f5 f = (\x -> f (Left x), \x -> f (Right x))
```